# How to remove CSS class from multiple ID elements using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class

I have a code that removes a class from ID in a certain condition,
now I have more ID's that needs the same, how can I do it in an easy short way?

instead:

```
$("#id-1").removeClass("otout");
$("#id-2").removeClass("otout");
$("#id-3").removeClass("otout");
$("#id-4").removeClass("otout");
```

Something like this:

```
$("id-1, id-2, id-3, id-4").removeClass("otout");
```

Any chance it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to prefix each **id** by '**#**', try this :

```
$("#id-1, #id-2, #id-3, #id-4").removeClass("otout");
```

Comment: Jeez, dude, you are handsome (I hope I won't get banned for it, just wanted to make you feel good. Good luck building your career in IT!).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the example should accomplish the task, as long as the selector string `id` is prefixed with `#`

```
$("#id-1, #id-2, #id-3, #id-4").removeClass("otout")
```

or

```
$("[id|=id]").removeClass("otout")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no jQuery tag, so here's a POJS version:

```js
function removeRed() {
  document.querySelectorAll('#sp-0, #sp-1, #sp-2, #sp-3')
    .forEach(node => node.classList.remove('red'));
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span id="sp-0" class="red">sp-0</span><br>
<span id="sp-1" class="red">sp-1</span><br>
<span id="sp-2" class="red">sp-2</span><br>
<span id="sp-3" class="red">sp-3</span><br>
<button onclick="removeRed()">Remove red</button>
```